# Let $x$ be a rational number. Prove that if the product $xy$ is irrational, then $y$ is irrational.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $x$ be a rational number. Prove that if the product $xy$ is irrational, then $y$ is irrational.

Suppose $x$, $y$ are both rational numbers. The product of two rational numbers will always yield another rational number, thus it cant be the case that $xy$ is irrational. If $y$ is rational then $xy$ is rational. Therefore if $xy$ is irrational then $y$ is irrational.

Is it insufficient to just say the product of two rational numbers is also rational? If it is sufficient how can I argue that it is?

Comment: Proving that if $y$ is rational then $xy$ is rational too is equivalent to the statement you like to prove. You have to assume that $x\neq 0$ though otherwise your statement is not true if $x=0$.

Comment: A proof should always be aimed at a particular readership.  What is sufficient at one level may not be at another.  IMHO your proof would be fine for upper secondary school or later.  If you are aiming at a less experienced audience, then perhaps you should say a bit more.

Comment: @Gary I was told "Within your proof, you must illustrate that x and y are rational by showing the result for defined rational numbers. Just stating that the product is rational is insufficient." but others tell me that its not neccesary as that is something for the reader of the proof to figure out. Even the book "how to prove it" states something similar and i quote "Occasionally, in a very complicated proof, a mathematician
may include some discussion of the strategy behind the proof to make the
proof easier to read. Usually, however, it is up to readers to figure this out
for themselves"

Comment: @David The proof was only read by my teacher who is a mathematician. Can i argue them marking my answer wrong? Because i really dont think its fair that the "correctness" of my answer is subjective

Comment: In courses I teach, we say something like this for proofs: "your proof should be understandable to another student who is also doing this course and has been studying conscientiously".  If when setting the assignment, your teacher did not give any indication of the level expected, then this would be something worth discussing with him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x, y$ are rational, let $x=\frac{a}{b}, y=\frac{c}{d}$. Then, $xy=\frac{ac}{bd}$. By the definition of rational numbers, $xy$ is rational. And hence, we are done. Usually, this result is trivial.